# Jquery $.ajax function data parameters

Tags: jquery

ı need to send data one is array another is single data.

```
var img=$('#image').val(); // image name

var formdatas=($(this).serialize()); // data from form, including to many data

data:formdatas, //legal
data:{f:formdatas,r:img}, //legal but formdatas is an array ı cant send it like this
```

but ı need something like this.

```
data:{formdatas,r:img}, // this is not working
```

and this is my complete code, ı just need to send 2 different data.

```
$('#lastikekle').submit(function() {

    var resim=$('#resim').val();

    var formverileri=($(this).serialize());

    $.ajax({
              type:"POST",          
              url: "lastikekle.php",
              data:{formverileri,r:resim}, ????
              success: function(result){

                $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
                $("#dialog").html(result);
                                        }   
        });


    });
```

Comment: `serialize()` returns a string, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: (`.serialize` returns a string)

```
data: formdatas+'&r='+encodeURIComponent(img)
```

Edit: 
or you could use [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
$('#lastikekle').submit(function () {
    var resim = $('#resim').val();
    var formverileri = $(this).serializeArray();
    formverileri.r = resim;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "lastikekle.php",
        data: formverileri,
        success : function (result) {
            $("#dialog").dialog();
            $("#dialog").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I used to solve issues like that. But I noticed encoding issues with characters like éàè and so on. But if you pass a 'non-string' value to the ajax `data`, the encoding issues didn't occur. Maybe less important in languages where these characters aren't used, but it did put me off using strings as data.

Comment: Perfect solution :) I don't blame people for no knowing the encoding issues, because most languages don't really rely on accented characters. I really feel sorry for french/scandinavian programmers at times, encoding issues are downright annoying.